# Generic Partial Sum formula

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

How do you calculate the Partial sum of a series when the series starts at $0$ or $1$ or any other number  $>1$? E.g. what would be the value of:

$$(a)\qquad \sum_{n=2}^\infty \left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^n$$
$$(b)\qquad \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^n$$
$$(c)\qquad \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^n$$

or in a complicated series like this one:

$$\sum_{i = 2}^\infty -\frac{(2i-3)(i-3)}{(5i-8)(4i+1)}$$

does this converge or diverge?

Comment: For series $(a),(b),(c)$, check out the geometric series: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series. The general form is $$\sum_{n=k}^\infty x^n=\frac{x^k}{1-x}$$for $|x|<1$ and $k\in\{0,1,2,...\}$.

Comment: That is a lot of parentheses you used on the bottom series... but the hint to give there is that if you expect a series to converge the limit of the summands must be zero.  Ask yourself if that is the case here.  As for the first question, $\sum\limits_{n=a}^\infty f(n) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty f(n) - \sum\limits_{n=0}^{a-1}f(n)$.  In your case, calculate the sum as though it started from zero and then subtract the two unnecessary terms or the one unnecessary term, etc...

Answer (score 0):

If $\sum_{i = k}^\infty f(i)$ Converges, then Lim n -> $\infty$, f(n)=$0$.[Here k=$2$]

Check that in the Second Example ,  Lim n -> $\infty$, f(n)= $-1/10$.

Hence It Diverges.

Regarding the (a),(b),(c): Refer to the Comment by Dave.